# Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED error is shown

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

```
    String s1 = PasswordText4.getText();
    String s2 = ConfirmText4.getText();
    String s3 = NameText4.getText();
    String s4 = UsernameText4.getText();
    String s5 = jLabel16.getText();

    if (PasswordText4.getText().equals(ConfirmText4.getText()) && s1.length() != 0 && s3.length() != 0 && s1.length() >= 4 && s2.length() >= 4) {
        try {
            String sql
                    = "BEGIN"
                    + "UPDATE LOGIN SET USERNAME = ?, PASSWORD = ?, NAME = ?"
                    + "WHERE USERNAME = ?;"
                    + "commit;"
                    + "END;";
            CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);
            cstmt.setString(1, UsernameText4.getText());
            cstmt.setString(2, PasswordText4.getText());
            cstmt.setString(3, NameText4.getText());
            cstmt.setString(4, jLabel16.getText());

            //System.out.println(jLabel16.getText());

            int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
            int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to update?", "Warning", dialogButton);
            if (dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                cstmt.execute();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Information Updated");
                jLabel15.setText(NameText4.getText());
                jLabel16.setText(UsernameText4.getText());
                jLabel17.setText(PasswordText4.getText());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

What's wrong with this code? When I try to update my data, the Invalid SQL type:

> sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED error is shown.

Please help me find solution for my problem.

Thank you in advance for answer.

Comment: You are missing to add a space between your query parts : " UPDATE...etc..  Your query actually begins with `BEGINUPDATE` as it is. Consider printing your `sql` String to see what's wrong.

Comment: faced the same issue in IntelliJ. IntelliJ highlights the keywords like "Update", "AND", "FROM" in blue and if it is not highlighted then you know there is a space required in the previous line before the keyword.

Answer (score 9):

[Berger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5612858/berger) is right, you need to add spaces between your query parts, for example:

```
String sql = " BEGIN "
           + " UPDATE LOGIN SET USERNAME = ?, PASSWORD = ?, NAME = ? "
           + " WHERE USERNAME = ?; "
           + " commit; "
           + " END;" ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Friends,

I too encountered the same issue when I execute a sequence of SQL queries (few queries are commented thru my Java program

Solution: Remove all commented SQL lines and then execute, you will not get "UNINITIALIED" error any more.

Comment: I received this exact error when executing the SQL Advisor. Removing the comments from the query did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something likewise,

```
String sql = "UPDATE LOGIN SET USERNAME = ?, PASSWORD = ?, NAME = ? WHERE USERNAME = ?" 

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement .setString(1, UsernameText4.getText());
preparedStatement .setString(2, PasswordText4.getText());
preparedStatement .setString(3, NameText4.getText());
preparedStatement .setString(4, jLabel16.getText());

preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
....
dbConnection.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error in CloudBeaver while executing PL/SQL script through "Execute SQL Script". It did not like the ending slash "/".

Answer (score 0):

java.sql.sqlexception: Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED

This error occurs when there is syntax error. check your syntax, Print the query and run the same query on your SQL client tool like SQL Developer, Toad, DBeaver..,

Example: consider below is the o/p of Sysout

> [select * from dual] & ["select * from dual"] //sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED

> select * from dual // This is good

Note all three queries run, but first two needs to be replace and []"" has to be removed before sending it for execution.