# Pass custom type to Oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have C++ code which use `#include <occi.h>`:

```
std::vector< std::string > arr{"qw", "er", "ty"};
stmt = conn->createStatement(
  "BEGIN Clear_labels(:p_list1); END;");
setVector(stmt,1,arr,"MYCUSTOMTYPE");
stmt->execute();
```

Now I want to write PL/SQL command to send same commad to DB.

MYCUSTOMTYPE:

```
TYPE "MYCUSTOMTYPE" as table of varchar2(255)
```

I think it should be something like this:

```
DECLARE list MYCUSTOMTYPE := MYCUSTOMTYPE("qw", "er", "ty")
BEGIN Clear_labels(list); END;
/
```

but I get error:

```
Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED

org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [17439] [99999]: Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:134)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:467)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$0(SQLQueryJob.java:407)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:146)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:405)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:849)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsContainer.readData(SQLEditor.java:2727)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:98)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:146)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:96)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:74)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:30)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:931)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1150)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1792)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1745)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:334)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.execute(JDBCStatementImpl.java:338)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:131)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Show us the definition of `MYCUSTOMTYPE` and also `Clean_labels`

Comment: where is MYCUSTOMTYPE defined? and what do you mean by "it doesn't work"

Comment: I updated post.

Comment: [Potentially related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36447240/invalid-sql-type-sqlkind-uninitialized-error-is-shown), but please show the actual code that led to that error.

Comment: I added more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to try the `sqlplus` and it turned out to be successful:

```
$ sqlplus tests/tests@cdb1

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Thu May 9 02:22:50 2019

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> DECLARE         
  2  p_list1 MYCUSTOMTYPE := MYCUSTOMTYPE('qw', 'er', 'ty');
  3  BEGIN
  4  Clear_labels(p_list1);
  5  END;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

I think the problem in `DBeaver`.